# Multiple forms on page, using 'this' and trying to carry over 'this' properties to another function

Tags: javascript, forms, this

Having a problem that is probably a bit hard to explain, so I'll do my best. I've been playing around with trying to create a simple JavaScript to-do app. I have multiple forms on the page that all correspond to an individual date (Jan 1, Jan 2, etc.). Each form of course has inputs, in this case, each form has 4 child nodes (What, Where, When, and the submit button).

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta description="Gallery, Javascript">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css" media="screen" />
        <title>Creating a simple to-do app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outerWrapper">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header id="header">
                <h1>A simple to-do app</h1>
            </header>
            <section id="todo">
                <div class="oneDateSection">
                    <div class="orangeBox">
                        <h1>January 1st, 2013</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oneDateSectionList">
                        <form method="POST" class="formList" action="">
                            <div><label for="what">What:</label><input type="text" name="what" class="what" id="what" /></div>
                            <div><label for="where">Where:</label><input type="text" name="where" class="where" id="where" /></div>
                            <div><label for="what">When:</label><input type="text" name="when" class="when" id="when"/></div>
                            <div><input type="submit" value="Add!" name="submit" class="submit" /></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="oneDateSection">
                    <div class="orangeBox">
                        <h1>January 2nd, 2013</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oneDateSectionList">
                        <form method="POST" class="formList" action="">
                            <div><label for="what">What:</label><input type="text" name="what" class="what" id="what" /></div>
                            <div><label for="where">Where:</label><input type="text" name="where" class="where" id="where" /></div>
                            <div><label for="what">When:</label><input type="text" name="when" class="when" id="when"/></div>
                            <div><input type="submit" value="Add!" name="submit" class="submit" /></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="oneDateSection">
                    <div class="orangeBox">
                        <h1>January 3rd, 2013</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oneDateSectionList">
                        <form method="POST" class="formList" action="">
                            <div><label for="what">What:</label><input type="text" name="what" class="what" id="what" /></div>
                            <div><label for="where">Where:</label><input type="text" name="where" class="where" id="where" /></div>
                            <div><label for="what">When:</label><input type="text" name="when" class="when" id="when"/></div>
                            <div><input type="submit" value="Add!" name="submit" class="submit" /></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="oneDateSection">
                    <div class="orangeBox">
                        <h1>January 4th, 2013</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oneDateSectionList">
                        <form method="POST" class="formList" action="">
                            <div><label for="what">What:</label><input type="text" name="what" class="what" id="what" /></div>
                            <div><label for="where">Where:</label><input type="text" name="where" class="where" id="where" /></div>
                            <div><label for="what">When:</label><input type="text" name="when" class="when" id="when"/></div>
                            <div><input type="submit" value="Add!" name="submit" class="submit" /></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="oneDateSection">
                    <div class="orangeBox">
                        <h1>January 5th, 2013</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oneDateSectionList">
                        <form method="POST" class="formList" action="">
                            <div><label for="what">What:</label><input type="text" name="what" class="what" id="what" /></div>
                            <div><label for="where">Where:</label><input type="text" name="where" class="where" id="where" /></div>
                            <div><label for="what">When:</label><input type="text" name="when" class="when" id="when"/></div>
                            <div><input type="submit" value="Add!" name="submit" class="submit" /></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="oneDateSection">
                    <div class="orangeBox">
                        <h1>January 6th, 2013</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oneDateSectionList">
                        <form method="POST" class="formList" action="">
                            <div><label for="what">What:</label><input type="text" name="what" class="what" id="what" /></div>
                            <div><label for="where">Where:</label><input type="text" name="where" class="where" id="where" /></div>
                            <div><label for="what">When:</label><input type="text" name="when" class="when" id="when"/></div>
                            <div><input type="submit" value="Add!" name="submit" class="submit" /></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="oneDateSection">
                    <div class="orangeBox">
                        <h1>January 7th, 2013</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oneDateSectionList">
                        <form method="POST" class="formList" action="">
                            <div><label for="what">What:</label><input type="text" name="what" class="what" id="what" /></div>
                            <div><label for="where">Where:</label><input type="text" name="where" class="where" id="where" /></div>
                            <div><label for="what">When:</label><input type="text" name="when" class="when" id="when"/></div>
                            <div><input type="submit" value="Add!" name="submit" class="submit" /></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="todo2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var utilities = {
    $: function(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
    },
    addEvent: function(obj, type, fn) {
        if (obj && obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        } else if (obj && obj.attachEvent) {
            obj.attachEvent("on" + type, fn);
        }
    }
}

function removeErrorMessage(id) {
    'use strict';
    var span = utilities.$(id + 'Error');
    if(span) {
        span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
    }
}


function addErrorMessage(id, msg) {
    'use strict';
    var elem = utilities.$(ID);
    var newID = id + "Error";
    var span = utilities.$(newID);

    if(span) {
        span.firstChild.value = msg;
    } else {
        span = document.createElement("span");
        span.setAttribute("class", "error");
        span.setAttribute("id", newID);
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
        elem.parentNode.appendChild(span);
    }
}


function storeInformation(e) {
    'use strict';
    if (e == "undefined") {
        e = window.event;
    }

    //Reference what, where and when input elements in form that calls this function
    var whatElements = this.getElementsByClassName("what");
    var whereElements = this.getElementsByClassName("where");
    var whenElements = this.getElementsByClassName("when");

    //Create object to store information
    var information = {
        what: whatElements[0].value,
        where: whereElements[0].value,
        when: whenElements[0].value,
        postedDate: new Date()
    }
    //Create HTML that will display information from form
    var output =    "What: " + information.what + "<br />" + 
                    "Where: " + information.where + "<br />" + 
                    "When: " + information.when + "<br />" +
                    "Posted: " + information.postedDate;

    //So you have TWO options. Either you have filled it out, or you haven't.

    //First case, and main IF: Some part of the form hasn't been filled out
    if ( (information.what == "") || (information.where == "") || (information.when == "") ) {

        //If the 'what' form field is empty
        if (information.what == "") {
            addErrorMessage(this.what, "Please enter what!");
        } else {
            removeErrorMessage(this.getElementById("what"));
        }

        //If the 'where' form field is empty
        if(information.where == "") {
            addErrorMessage(this.where, "Please enter where!");
        } else {
            removeErrorMessage(this.getElementById("where"));
        }

        //If the 'when' form field is empty
        if(information.when == "") {
            addErrorMessage(this.when, "Please enter when!");
        } else {
            removeErrorMessage(this.getElementById("when"));
        }

    //OR, all the form fields HAVE BEEN FILLED OUT.
    } else {
        if (paragraph) {
            paragraph.innerHTML = output;
        } else {    
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.setAttribute("class", "outputDiv");
            var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
            paragraph.setAttribute("class", "outputParagraph");
            newDiv.appendChild(paragraph);
            paragraph.innerHTML = output;
            //Append everything
            whatElements[0].parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(newDiv);
        }
    }

    //Prevent form from submitting
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
    return false;
}

window.onload = function() {
    'use strict';
    var allForms = document.getElementsByClassName("formList");
    for (var i = 0, count = allForms.length; i < count; i++) {
        utilities.addEvent(allForms[i], "submit", storeInformation);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm sure there are probably layout issues, and improper JS here (if you could point that out to me, that would be a bonus). However, my issue is with the **this** keyword. In the JS, I am using this.what, this.where and this.when to refer to the form's input ID's. I am using 'this' because the there are multiple forms on the page that I give an event listener to, so that, in practical use, whatever form the end-user uses, it will store the right information.

The problem is in my 'addErrorMessage' function, 'elem' is said to be null. After stepping through the process with Chrome's debugger, the ID being passed to addErrorMessage as the parameter still refers to the form, but doesn't get stored in elem for some reason.

I'm thinking that 'this.what', for example, cannot be carried over to another function? ie., the form referring to its own properties cannot be used in another function? I'm not sure what the problem is. Chrome tells me the value of 'this.what' references correctly, and is passed to 'addErrorMessage', but no-dice trying to store this information in 'elem'.

Can anyone help? I'm not that much of a JS guy right now so please be easy on me. Apologies for the long question!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = utilities.$(ID);
```

should be

```
var elem = utilities.$(id);
```